# If you sign up to Ask Ubuntu via Launchpad, would a profile get created on the wider SE network?

Tags: support, login, launchpad, openid

Launchpad authentication is only available on AU. If you use that to create an AU profile, would doing so create a profile for you on the rest of the network?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it should.

**However, you cannot use your Launchpad OAuth login on any site other than Ask Ubuntu.**  So you should also add either a StackExchange local login or a secondary login from, say, Google or Facebook, in order to authenticate to other sites (when cross-site cookies don't work or such).